# Extracting output of Linux "time" command into a file

Tags: linux, shell, time, raspberry-pi, gnuplot

I want to run the following Linux command a number of times in a loop and want to plot the variations in **real** time using gnuplot.

```
time scp -i k30.pem ubuntu@ec2-XX-YY-ZZ-WW.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/pics/*  /home/pi/
```

But I am facing problem of how to extract the output of above command into a spreadsheet column so that i could plot it using `gnuplot` later.
I am using latest version of Raspbian in my Raspberry Pi model 3B+.

Please help.

Comment: In order to get the output of `time` you need something like this (an example using `ls`): `(time ls) 2> tmp`. The file `tmp` will have the desired output.

Comment: Try this `result=$(/usr/bin/time sleep 3  2>&1)` then `echo $result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU [`time`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) has `-o FILE` parameter that you can use to output the timing into a file. You can process the file, extract the timing from the file and put it somewhere in CSV or such in a loop.

It also has `-f format` option that lets you customize the output format of the `time`.

So, in your case it could go like this:

```sh
/usr/bin/time -o mytime.log -f "%e" scp -i k30.pem ubuntu@ec2-XX-YY-ZZ-WW.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/pics/* /home/pi/
```

In this command the `"%e"` format makes the GNU `time` print only elapsed real time in seconds.

Comment: This solution has two problems for me: 1. It is overwriting mytime.log. 2. time command is not at /usr/bin/time location in Raspbian. I check using whereis time it gives time: /usr/include/time.h /usr/share/man/man7/time.7.gz /usr/share/man/man2/time.2.gz
Then I tried replacing /usr/bin/time to /usr/include/time.h but it fails to Permission denied. Then I tried sudo but problem is same.

Comment: @PankajThakur I do not know Raspbian. I was assuming it was Debian based so it would have GNU tools. If it does not have the time command, you might have to install it using whatever packaging system it supports.

Comment: time command is available in Rasbian. Also my first problem was resolved by replacing  -o with -ao on ubuntu 18.04.